# SONARQUBEE 10.1 - Podman/Docker - Failed to authenticate with proxy

Tags: proxy, sonarqube, podman

I succeeded deploying SonarQube EE 10.1 on Podman environment with ansible.

My LDAP connection works fine, but when I try to reach the [update center](https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties)  I received the failed authentication on my Proxy.

**What I can confirm:**
The user and password is not send to the proxy authentication
[Connection KO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1kDg.png)

In my old version of SonarQube community on docker, I have the correct authentication:
[connection OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt2MP.png)

**My setup:**

- podman version 4.4.1
- sonarqube:10.1.0-enterprise
- database: postgres:15.3-alpine
- input traefik: traefik:v2.10.4

**Env:**

```
sonarqube@7df9ce24de95:/opt/sonarqube$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.8 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**My service start:**

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman container run \
        --cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id \
        --cgroups=no-conmon \
        --rm \
        --sdnotify=conmon \
        --replace \
        --name sonarqube \
        --network bridge \
        --env "SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar" \
        --env "SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD=xxxxx" \
        --env "SONAR_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxx:5432/sonar" \
        --env "SONAR_CORE_SERVERBASEURL=https://xxxxxx.com" \
        --env "SONAR_WEB_HTTP_MINTHREADS=5" \
        --env "SONAR_WEB_HTTP_ACCEPTCOUNT=25" \
        --env "SONAR_WEB_HTTP_KEEPALIVETIMEOUT=60000" \
        --env "SONAR_WEB_SESSIONTIMEOUTINMINUTES=480" \
        --env "SONAR_WEB_JAVAOPTS=-Xmx1g -Xms1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" \
        --env "SONAR_WEB_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes= -Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes= " \
        --env "SONAR_CE_JAVAOPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g" \
        --env "SONAR_CE_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes= -Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes= " \
        --env "SONAR_SECURITY_REALM=LDAP" \
        --env "LDAP_URL=ldap://xxxxx:yyyyy" \
        --env "LDAP_BINDDN=ulosvc@xxxxxx.com" \
        --env "LDAP_BINDPASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx" \
        --env "LDAP_USER_BASEDN=DC=xxxx,DC=xxxxxx-net,DC=com" \
        --env "LDAP_USER_REALNAMEATTRIBUTE=sAMAccountName" \
        --env "LDAP_USER_REQUEST=(&(objectClass=user)(|(memberOf=CN=xxxxxxx,OU=Groupes,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxxx-net,DC=com))(sAMAccountName={login}))" \
        --env "HTTP_PROXYHOST=proxy.xxxxxxx.com" \
        --env "HTTPS_PROXYHOST=proxy.xxxxxxx.comm" \
        --env "HTTP_PROXYPORT=8080" \
        --env "HTTPS_PROXYPORT=8080" \
        --env "HTTP_PROXYUSER=Proxy-xxxxx" \
        --env "HTTP_PROXYPASSWORD=xxxxxxx" \
        --env "HTTPS_PROXYUSER=Proxy-xxxxx" \
        --env "HTTPS_PROXYPASSWORD=xxxxxxx" \
        --env "SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAOPTS=-Xmx4g -Xms4g" \
        --env "SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" \
        --env "SONAR_CE_PARALLELPROJECTTASKS=True" \
        --label traefik.enable=true \
        --label traefik.http.routers.sonarqube.rule=Host(`xxxxxx.com`) \
        --label traefik.http.routers.sonarqube.entrypoints=https \
        --label traefik.http.routers.sonarqube.tls=true \
        --label traefik.http.routers.sonarqube.tls.options=myTLSOptions@file \
        --label traefik.http.services.sonarqube.loadbalancer.server.port=9000 \
        --publish 9000:9000 \
        --volume sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data:rw,U \
        --volume sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs:rw,U \
        --volume sonarqube_extensions_plugins:/opt/sonarqube/extensions:rw,U \
        --detach=True sonarqube:10.1.0-enterprise
```

**Sonarqube log:**

```
2023.09.04 12:39:51 ERROR web[AYpgNL31HNLjkonIAAAb][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Fail to connect to update center
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties
        at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader.failToDownload(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:151)
        at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader.readString(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:107)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.UriReader.readString(UriReader.java:69)
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.UpdateCenterClient.init(UpdateCenterClient.java:111)
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.UpdateCenterClient.getUpdateCenter(UpdateCenterClient.java:94)
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.UpdateCenterMatrixFactory.getUpdateCenter(UpdateCenterMatrixFactory.java:44)
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ws.AvailableAction.handle(AvailableAction.java:84)
        at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:111)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:84)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$JavaxFilterAdapter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:227)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:198)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$HttpFilterChainAdapter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:241)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SonarLintConnectionFilter.doFilter(SonarLintConnectionFilter.java:66)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$JavaxFilterAdapter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:227)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:198)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:146)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:70)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CspFilter.doFilter(CspFilter.java:63)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:60)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:47)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:57)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:66)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:65)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:115)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:137)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.kt:476)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.kt:262)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
        at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader.executeCall(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:147)
        at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader.readString(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:104)
        ... 149 common frames omitted
```

I tried plenty of solutions available on the internet with the setup of several parameters unsuccessfully:

- With or without: jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes & jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes
- I try to set or not all proxy information describe here: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/setup-and-upgrade/configure-and-operate-a-server/environment-variables/#update-center
- I try also to set http & https proxy in var pod env.
- I also try to use the **sonar.propertie** file to avoid to use --env parameters

Expect:

Any idea or solution to investigate.
Maybe the trouble is not in SonarQube but somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with 9.9 lts communauty edition deployed on a docker swarm.
Proxy host and port are correctly take into account but user and password seems to not to be send  to the proxy. I have try env var, java additional properties, modify sonar.properties files.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy authentication is not working in SONARQUBE 9.9, 10 and 10.2 due to a bug.
The issue can be tracked here [SONAR-20540](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SONAR-20540)